# Is there an example of a continuous chaotic mapping?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, continuity, fractals, chaos-theory

I studied a bit of chaos in college, but from my learning, I've never known a mapping that does not consist of discrete orbits. For example, take the Mandelbrot set, where the points on the mapping are simply iterations of the function:
$f(x), f^2(x), f^3(x), ...$

And so my conclusion has always been that a chaotic mapping is necessarily both discontinuous and countable.

But is that true?

Comment: The [Lorenz system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_system) is a textbook example of a continuous system with chaotic behavior

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chaotic_maps